# Importing modules from another TypeScript project using project references

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a project structure like this:

```
Proj1\src\file1.ts
Proj1\src\tsconfig.json

Proj2\src\file2.ts
Proj2\src\tsconfig.json
```

Now, both are module files, and Proj2's `tsconfig.json` references `../../Proj1/src`.

Is there any point to project references in this case?  It seems like `file2.ts` still requires a full relative path into the other project, like this:

```
import { file1 } from "../../Proj1/src/file1";
```

Now I have two paths to project 1 (the reference and the import), meaning the project reference is only useful (for module projects) to maintain build order only.  Is there another way to reference modules from a referenced project and have TypeScript figure out the paths for me? I'm just asking in case I'm missing something.  I'm also up very late and probably half asleep, so there's that lol. ;)

Comment: I have the same question. I have to reference files from other projects using absolute paths (ie. starting from the other projects rootDir). This includes triple-slash imports to files from other projects, for example `/// <reference path='otherproject/src/utilities.ts'/>`. Is this at all possible with TS?

Comment: You can easily include other .ts files in the tsconfig.json file (in the correct order you need), so I do t think you need to use comment references (unless you don’t want to use the config file).